# Mixed scala/java gradle project cannot properly load dependencies

Tags: java, scala, gradle

I have a problem compiling mixed Java/Scala project using gradle. I have Java classes in `src/main/java` and scala ones in `src/main/scala`. To this point I was using maven without any problems but now I needed to convert it into gradle.

The problem I have is that scala classes are not seen during complication. I found a possible solution to this problem by defining source sets, I also use own dependency from local artifactory, the final **build.gralde**  looks similar to this

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.3.RELEASE"

    }
}

apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group = 'some.package'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8


dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.12'
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.11.12'
    compile 'my.dependency:artifact:version'
}

sourceSets {
    main.scala.srcDirs = ["src/main/scala", "src/main/java"]
    main.java.srcDirs = []
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '5.1.1'
}
```

As you can see, I included sourceSets. I found that this should fix problems, unfortunately with this I have problems with my own dependency and I get errors like that:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileScala'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:119)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.execute(ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:93)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:45)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: my/dependency/SomeClass
        at sbt.ClassToAPI$.structure(ClassToAPI.scala:77)
        at sbt.ClassToAPI$.x$2$lzycompute$1(ClassToAPI.scala:66)
        at sbt.ClassToAPI$.x$2$1(ClassToAPI.scala:66)
        at sbt.ClassToAPI$.instance$lzycompute$1(ClassToAPI.scala:66)
        at sbt.ClassToAPI$.sbt$ClassToAPI$$instance$1(ClassToAPI.scala:66)
        at sbt.ClassToAPI$$anonfun$5.apply(ClassToAPI.scala:67)
        at sbt.ClassToAPI$$anonfun$5.apply(ClassToAPI.scala:67)
        at xsbti.SafeLazy$Impl._t$lzycompute(SafeLazy.scala:18)
        at xsbti.SafeLazy$Impl._t(SafeLazy.scala:16)
        at xsbti.SafeLazy$Impl.get(SafeLazy.scala:22)
        at sbt.ClassToAPI$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ClassToAPI.scala:22)
        at sbt.ClassToAPI$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ClassToAPI.scala:22)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.foreach(ListBuffer.scala:45)
        at sbt.ClassToAPI$.process(ClassToAPI.scala:22)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.sbt$compiler$AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$$readAPI$1(AggressiveCompile.scala:130)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileJava$1$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:138)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileJava$1$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:138)
        at sbt.classfile.Analyze$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(Analyze.scala:44)
        at sbt.classfile.Analyze$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(Analyze.scala:43)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
        at sbt.classfile.Analyze$.apply(Analyze.scala:43)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileJava$1$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:138)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileJava$1$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:136)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileJava$1$2.apply$mcV$sp(AggressiveCompile.scala:136)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileJava$1$2.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:136)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileJava$1$2.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:136)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.sbt$compiler$AggressiveCompile$$timed(AggressiveCompile.scala:168)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.compileJava$1(AggressiveCompile.scala:135)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:142)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:84)
        at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:66)
        at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:64)
        at sbt.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(IncrementalCommon.scala:32)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:72)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:71)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:99)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:71)
        at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:54)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile2(AggressiveCompile.scala:159)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile1(AggressiveCompile.scala:68)
        at com.typesafe.zinc.Compiler.compile(Compiler.scala:207)
        at com.typesafe.zinc.Compiler.compile(Compiler.scala:189)
        at com.typesafe.zinc.Compiler.compile(Compiler.scala:180)
        at com.typesafe.zinc.Compiler.compile(Compiler.scala:171)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.scala.ZincScalaCompiler$Compiler.execute(ZincScalaCompiler.java:81)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.scala.ZincScalaCompiler.execute(ZincScalaCompiler.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.scala.ZincScalaCompiler.execute(ZincScalaCompiler.java:38)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerCallable.call(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:86)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerCallable.call(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:74)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:42)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.execute(WorkerDaemonServer.java:36)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction.run(WorkerAction.java:110)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
```

It seems like scala has problems with picking up dependencies from **build.gradle**. I cannot find any information about how to fix it.

Comment: did you try to rebuild the project? also, when you say *are not seen during compilation* - you mean are not seen from the `java` classes?

Comment: Yes, they are not seen from Java classes, I get a lot of "package does not exist" and "cannot find symbol" errors. Rebuilding outside of gradle results in Scala classes not being seen also in Java classes. I also tried clearing gradle cache but it did not help.